# Spring Boot and/or Vaadin autowiring behaviors I do not understand

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, vaadin

I am working on a Spring Boot application an am having issues where items are not being auto-wired as I expect. What is adding to this confusion is that I have another Spring Boot application that also happens to involve Vaadin. In this application, auto-wiring seems more "automated".

Here is what I mean. In the Vaadin app, a `@Service` object, is injected into a Vaadin "view" with little effort. Additionally, the service object itself is injected with a `Repository` object. I need to do almost nothing to make this all happen.

In my other **non-Vaadin** application, I set up the code to do similar things, but in this case, it does not work. The application fails to start and complains as below:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.mycompany.app.backend.service.TaskMasterService required a bean of type 'com.mycompany.app.backend.repository.TaskMasterRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.mycompany.app.backend.repository.TaskMasterRepository' in your configuration.
```

I assume that I'm missing some configuration somewhere, or that the Vaadin application has "extra" functionality added that makes this work.

Here are snippets of the **Vaadin** application:

TasksView.java:

```
@Route("main")
public class TasksView extends VerticalLayout {

  private final TaskService     taskService;
  private final TaskNoteService noteService;

  public TasksView(TaskService taskService, TaskNoteService noteService) {
    this.taskService = taskService;
    this.noteService = noteService;
  }
  ...
}
```

TaskService.java:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TaskService {

  private TaskRepository      taskRepo;

  public TaskService(TaskRepository taskRepo) {
    this.taskRepo = taskRepo;
  }
  ...
}
```

TaskRepository.java:

```
public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long>, TaskRepositoryCustom {
  ...
}
```

I don't need to `@Autowired` anything or provide a `@Configuration` class or define a `@Bean` anywhere. It just works.

Here are some snippets from the **non-Vaadin** application:

IngesterRunner.java:

```
@Service
public class IngesterRunner {

  private TaskMasterService       tmService;
  private TaskRelationshipService trService;
  private VariantDetailService    vdService;

  public IngesterRunner(TaskMasterService tmService, TaskRelationshipService trService,
      VariantDetailService vdService) {
    this.tmService = tmService;
    this.trService = trService;
    this.vdService = vdService;
  }
  ...
}
```

TaskMasterService.java:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TaskMasterService {

  private final TaskMasterRepository repo;

  public TaskMasterService(TaskMasterRepository repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
  }
  ...
}
```

TaskMasterRepository.java:

```
package com.mycompany.app.backend.repository;

public interface TaskMasterRepository extends JpaRepository<TaskMaster, Long> {
}
```

JPAConfiguration.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.mycompany.app.backend.repository", transactionManagerRef = "jpaTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfiguration {
    
  private static final String[] ENTITY_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = {
      "com.mycompany.app.backend.entity" };
  ...
}
```

I don't understand what is different about the first application that makes auto-wiring work so much more smoothly. Is it something I have in my pom.xml? Is it some sort of extra support provided by Vaadin?

If requested, I can try to include the POM files if that will help.

**Update**:

I have tried a number of suggestions, but none seem to have any effect. I added `@Autowired` annotations, but it makes no difference.

```
@Service
public class IngesterRunner {
  private TaskMasterService       tmService;
  private TaskRelationshipService trService;
  private VariantDetailService    vdService;

  public IngesterRunner(@Autowired TaskMasterService tmService,
      @Autowired TaskRelationshipService trService, @Autowired VariantDetailService vdService) {
    this.tmService = tmService;
    this.trService = trService;
    this.vdService = vdService;
  }
  ...
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class TaskMasterService {
  private final TaskMasterRepository repo;

  public TaskMasterService(@Autowired TaskMasterRepository repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried starting with debug to see if everything is picked up properly?

Comment: Describe what you mean by "starting with debug"? Are you referring to the debugger in eclipse (the IDE I'm using) or something else?

Comment: I mean e.g. runnting with `--debug` or what is best for your scenario.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-startup-failure

Comment: In the Vaadin app's case, it's the `@Route` annotation that enables the DI to work. See `VaadinServletContextInitializer` in `vaadin-spring` if you're interested in the dirty details.

Comment: Ah, so my theory was not far off the mark.

Comment: @ollitietavainen Are you referring to the javadocs or is there documentation that discusses how this class works and how it can be used?

Comment: There's no point in using `VaadinServletContextInitializer` in a non-Vaadin app. I'm just answering your question "I don't understand what is different about the first application that makes auto-wiring work so much more smoothly. Is it something I have in my pom.xml? Is it some sort of extra support provided by Vaadin?." It's a "comment" instead of an "answer" since it doesn't directly help you in solving your problem.

Comment: Sources here: https://github.com/vaadin/spring/blob/master/vaadin-spring/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/spring/VaadinServletContextInitializer.java

Answer (score 0):

@Repository annotation in TaskMasterRepository.java, like

```
@Repository
public interface TaskMasterRepository extends JpaRepository<TaskMaster, Long> {
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it made no difference. Same result. Also, I did not have to do that in the Vaadin application - if that makes any difference.

Comment: ok! before `@SpringBootApplication` in your code add this `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation, while doing this pls make sure `@Repository` should be there for TaskMasterRepository.java

Comment: I forgot that I had left out the JPAConfiguration code.

Comment: ok!  while injecting the class dependencies, `@Autowired`  annotation need to be used na. This is my suggestion.